# json_decode returns JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX but text is valid JSON

Tags: php, html, json, string, tags

I have a long JSON text that contains the description of an article in 6 languages.
So I have something like:

```
{"it":"html text", "en":"html text", "fr":"html text", "de":"html text", "es":"html text", "pt":"html text"}
```

Trying to read JSON on https://jsonlint.com/, it says that JSON is valid but my JSON_DECODE function can't decode it.

With my JSON_DECODE function I have no problem with any type of JSON, but not with this text.

This is my JSON_DECODE function:

```
public static function JSON_DECODE($valore)
{
    $valore ??= '';

    $counter = 0;

    if ($valore == '') {
        $valore = [];
    }

    $trimmed = is_string($valore) ? trim($valore, '"') : $valore;
    if (is_string($trimmed) && !Utility::isJson($trimmed)) {
        return $valore;
    }

    if (is_string($valore) || is_null($valore)) {
        $valore = str_replace('&quot;', '"', $valore);

        while (!is_null($valore) && !is_array($valore) && $counter < 30) {
            if (is_null(json_decode($valore, true)) && $counter == 0) {
                Utility::rimuoviQuot($valore);
            }
            $valore = json_decode($valore, true);
            $counter++;
        }

        if (is_array($valore)) {
            foreach ($valore as $index => $value) {
                if (is_string($value) && Utility::isJson($value)) {
                    $value = Utility::JSON_DECODE($value);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (is_null($valore)) {
        $valore = [];
    }

    return $valore;
}

public static function isJson($value)
{
    if (is_null($value)) {
        return false;
    }

    $value = str_replace('&quot;', '"', $value);

    if (gettype($value) != gettype('')) {
        if (gettype($value) == gettype([])) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @json_decode($value, true);

    return (json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE);
}
```

I don't know why, but it can't decode my text.. can you please help me?

Here is the full text:
https://traff.co/9Qj8z6O0

I tried all:
utf8_decode, mb_convert_encoding, htmlentites, html_entity_decode stripsplashes, preg_replace, trim, rtrim... but nothing works.
I just want to decode it as an array.

Comment: `Trying to read JSON on https://jsonlint.com/ it says that JSON is valid, but my JSON_DECODE function can't decode it.`...presumably what you pasted into JSONline isn't exactly the same as what is being passed into PHP's `json_decode()` function. But also, I pasted the text you gave at https://traff.co/9Qj8z6O0 into jsonlint.com and it gives an error. It's _not_ valid JSON.

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of all the stuff in your custom `JSON_DECODE` function? What is it trying to achieve, and why?

Comment: Why would you ever write your own [JSON decode function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)?

Comment: [THIS is valid](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/4yaog8fd/) - you had missing `"` and none of the embedded dialogues had escaped double quotes `\"`

Comment: @mplungjan I didn't understand where is the problem.
Anyway, i put it on my db row, next I tried to save it with ckeditor and the JSON broke again, so I think ckeditor does something with the quotes..

Comment: That's very likely. CKEditor is a HTML editor, it's not designed to work with JSON. It's unclear what you are trying to achieve by using JSON here. If you have multiple different translations of the text, I'd suggest storing each one in a separate DB row, instead of trying to put it in a giant JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @mplungjan, you are missing escape character for " (double quotes) in your value. Please use the JSON below and test it again. And please make sure to include your JSON data in the question next time do not just link it, as link contents tend to change overtime.

```
{
    "it": "<p><strong>Lapitec Chef</strong>, l'innovativo <strong>piano cottura a induzione sottotop</strong> che permette la massima pulizia formale dell’arredo, ha vinto il Kitchen Innovation Award 2023, premio promosso da LifeCare.Network UG e annunciato con cerimonia ufficiale alla fiera Ambiente di Francoforte.</p><p>A decretarne la vittoria è stato il pubblico che ha voluto eleggerlo come miglior prodotto secondo i criteri di “functionality, innovation, product benefit, design e material equality”.</p><p>“Si tratta del primo premio ottenuto da Lapitec Chef, che conferma la nostra ricerca verso l’innovazione e permette inoltre di esprimere le migliori caratteristiche della <strong>pietra sinterizzata</strong>” -  racconta <i>Marcello Toncelli</i>, alla guida del brand, che prosegue: “Abbiamo dedicato diversi anni alla messa a punto di questo prodotto, coperto da brevetto e sviluppato per la parte elettrotermica in collaborazione con l’Università di Padova. La nostra ambizione è far diventare Lapitec la <strong>superficie</strong> di riferimento per eccellenza nel mondo cucina, a livello internazionale, e Lapitec Chef è uno strumento indispensabile e unico attraverso il quale muoverci verso questo obiettivo”.</p><p> </p><h2>Lapitec Chef: mix tra estetica e tecnologia</h2><p>Caratterizzato da un mix perfetto tra estetica e tecnologia, performance e funzionalità, Lapitec Chef è azionato da un doppio Cooking Mat dotato di sensori magnetici; quando è posizionato sul piano, interagisce con gli induttori sotto-top e attiva i comandi touch e il sistema, per un totale di quattro aree cottura anche in modalità bridge. In assenza del Mat, il <strong>piano cottura a induzione</strong> e i relativi display risultano invece inattivi e garantiscono la massima sicurezza. Il <strong>top cucina</strong> resta quindi completamente libero: appare solo il display insieme a piccole incisioni che indicano dove posizionare il tappetino. Il <strong>piano di lavoro</strong> può essere impiegato così per la preparazione dei cibi, l’impiattamento o ancora come area pranzo, grazie alla sua superficie non porosa, inassorbente, resistente agli agenti chimici e agli sbalzi termici, certificata con il marchio NSF Food Zone per il contatto con gli alimenti.</p><p> </p><h2>Personalizzabile, silica free e ‘a tutta massa’</h2><p>Lapitec Chef è compatibile con tutte le stoviglie adatte a <strong>piani a induzione</strong>. Il Cooking Mat è realizzato in silicone alimentare di colore nero con un pattern superficiale che ne migliora il rendimento, ed è lavabile in lavastoviglie.</p><p>Esteticamente ricercato e tecnologicamente avanzato, Lapitec Chef è personalizzabile in tutte le nuance e finiture della gamma Lapitec, silica free e ‘a tutta massa’.</p><p><strong>Lapitec</strong> è infatti una <strong>pietra sinterizzata</strong> “a tutta massa”, realizzata con una miscela di minerali 100% naturali. Materiale utilizzato in architettura, interior e product design,  è disponibile in lastre di grandi dimensioni con tre possibili spessori (12, 20 e 30 mm), in 18 nuance e 6 finiture superficiali.</p>",
    "en": "<p><b>Lapitec Chef, </b>the <strong>innovative under-top&nbsp;induction hob</strong> that allows for maximum formal cleanliness of furnishings, won the Kitchen Innovation Award 2023, an award promoted by LifeCare.Network UG and announced with an official ceremony at the Ambiente fair in Frankfurt.</p>\n\n<p>The victory was decreed by the public who wanted to elect it as the best product according to the criteria of \"functionality, innovation, product benefit, design and material equality\".</p>\n\n<p>\"This is the first prize obtained by Lapitec Chef, which confirms our research towards innovation and also allows us to express the best characteristics of <strong>sintered stone</strong>\" - &nbsp;says Ma<em>rcello Toncelli,</em> at the helm of the brand, who continues: \"We have dedicated several years to the fine-tuning of this product, covered by a patent and developed for the electrothermal part in collaboration with the University of Padua. Our ambition is to make Lapitec the reference<strong> surface</strong> par excellence in the world of cooking, at an international level, and Lapitec Chef is an indispensable and unique tool through which we can move towards this goal\".</p>\n\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n\n<h2>Lapitec Chef: mix between aesthetics and technology</h2>\n\n<p>Characterized by a perfect mix of aesthetics and technology, performance and functionality, Lapitec Chef is activated by a double Cooking Mat equipped with magnetic sensors; when positioned on the hob, it interacts with the under-top inductors and activates the touch controls and the system, for a total of four cooking areas, even in bridge mode. In the absence of the Mat, the <strong>induction hob</strong> and the relative displays are instead inactive and guarantee maximum safety. The<strong> kitchen top</strong> therefore remains completely free: only the display appears together with small incisions that indicate where to place the mat. The <strong>worktop</strong> can thus be used for food preparation, plating or even as a dining area, thanks to its non-porous, non-absorbent surface, resistant to chemical agents and thermal shock, certified with the NSF Food Zone mark for contact with food.</p>\n\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n\n<h2>Customisable, silica free and full body</h2>\n\n<p>Lapitec Chef is compatible with all crockery suitable for <strong>induction hobs</strong>. The Cooking Mat is made of black food-grade silicone with a surface pattern that improves its performance, and is dishwasher safe.</p>\n\n<p>Aesthetically sophisticated and technologically advanced, Lapitec Chef can be customized in all the nuances and finishes of the Lapitec range, silica free and &#39;full body&#39;.</p>\n\n<p><b>Lapitec</b> is in fact a \"full body\" <strong>sintered stone</strong>, made with a mixture of 100% natural minerals. Material used in architecture, interior and product design, it is available in large slabs with three possible thicknesses (12, 20 and 30 mm), in 18 shades and 6 surface finishes.</p>\n",
    "fr": "<p><b>Lapitec Chef, </b>l&#39;innovante <strong>plaque de cuisson &agrave; induction sous-plan</strong> qui permet une propret&eacute; formelle maximale des meubles, a remport&eacute; le Kitchen Innovation Award 2023, un prix promu par LifeCare.Network UG et annonc&eacute; lors d&#39;une c&eacute;r&eacute;monie officielle &agrave; la foire Ambiente de Francfort.</p>\n\n<p>La victoire a &eacute;t&eacute; d&eacute;cern&eacute;e par le public qui a voulu l&#39;&eacute;lire meilleur produit selon les crit&egrave;res de \"fonctionnalit&eacute;, innovation, b&eacute;n&eacute;fice produit, design et &eacute;galit&eacute; mati&egrave;re\".</p>\n\n<p>\"Il s&#39;agit de la premi&egrave;re r&eacute;compense obtenue par Lapitec Chef, qui confirme notre recherche vers l&#39;innovation et nous permet &eacute;galement d&#39;exprimer les meilleures caract&eacute;ristiques de la <strong>pierre fritt&eacute;e</strong>\", d&eacute;clare M<em>arcello Toncelli,</em> &agrave; la t&ecirc;te de la marque, qui poursuit : \"Nous avons pass&eacute; plusieurs ann&eacute;es &agrave; mettre au point ce produit, couvert par un brevet et d&eacute;velopp&eacute; pour la partie &eacute;lectrothermique en collaboration avec l&#39;Universit&eacute; de Padoue. Notre ambition est de faire de Lapitec la <strong>surface</strong> de r&eacute;f&eacute;rence par excellence dans le monde de la cuisine, au niveau international, et Lapitec Chef est un outil indispensable et unique qui nous permet d&#39;avancer vers cet objectif\".</p>\n\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n\n<h2>Lapitec Chef : m&eacute;lange entre esth&eacute;tique et technologie</h2>\n\n<p>Caract&eacute;ris&eacute; par un m&eacute;lange parfait d&#39;esth&eacute;tique et de technologie, de performance et de fonctionnalit&eacute;, Lapitec Chef est activ&eacute; par un double tapis de cuisson &eacute;quip&eacute; de capteurs magn&eacute;tiques ; lorsqu&#39;il est positionn&eacute; sur la table de cuisson, il interagit avec les inducteurs situ&eacute;s sous le plan&nbsp;et active les commandes tactiles et le syst&egrave;me, pour un total de quatre zones de cuisson, m&ecirc;me en mode pont. En l&#39;absence du Mat, <strong>la plaque &agrave; induction</strong> et ses affichages sont inactifs et assurent une s&eacute;curit&eacute; maximale. Le<strong> plan de cuisine</strong> reste donc totalement libre : seul l&#39;&eacute;cran appara&icirc;t avec de petites incisions qui indiquent o&ugrave; placer le tapis. Le <strong>plan de travail</strong> peut ainsi &ecirc;tre utilis&eacute; pour la pr&eacute;paration des aliments, le dressage ou m&ecirc;me comme coin repas, gr&acirc;ce &agrave; sa surface non poreuse, non absorbante, r&eacute;sistante aux agents chimiques et aux chocs thermiques, certifi&eacute;e avec la marque NSF Food Zone pour le contact avec les aliments.</p>\n\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n\n<h2>Personnalisable, sans silice et &#39;pleine masse&#39;.</h2>\n\n<p>Lapitec Chef est compatible avec tous les<strong> ustensiles de cuisine</strong> adapt&eacute;s aux plaques &agrave; induction. Le tapis de cuisson est fabriqu&eacute; en silicone noir de qualit&eacute; alimentaire, avec un motif de surface qui am&eacute;liore les performances, et peut &ecirc;tre lav&eacute; au lave-vaisselle.</p>\n\n<p>Esth&eacute;tiquement recherch&eacute; et technologiquement avanc&eacute;, Lapitec Chef est personnalisable dans toutes les nuances et finitions de la gamme Lapitec, sans silice et &#39;pleine masse&#39;.</p>\n\n<p><b>Lapitec </b>est en effet une<strong> pierre fritt&eacute;e </strong>\"pleine masse\", r&eacute;alis&eacute;e avec un m&eacute;lange de min&eacute;raux 100% naturels. Mat&eacute;riau utilis&eacute; en architecture, int&eacute;rieur et design de produit, &nbsp;est disponible en grandes plaques avec trois &eacute;paisseurs possibles (12, 20 et 30 mm), en 18 nuances et 6 finitions de surface.</p>\n",
    "de": "<p><b>Lapitec Chef, </b>das innovative<b> Untertisch-Induktionskochfeld, </b>das eine maximale formale Sauberkeit des Mobiliars erm&ouml;glicht, wurde mit dem K&uuml;cheninnovationspreis 2023 ausgezeichnet, der von der LifeCare.Network UG gef&ouml;rdert und auf der Ambiente in Frankfurt feierlich verliehen wurde.</p>\n\n<p>Der Sieg wurde von der &Ouml;ffentlichkeit bestimmt, die es nach den Kriterien \"Funktionalit&auml;t, Innovation, Produktnutzen, Design und Materialgleichheit\" zum besten Produkt w&auml;hlen wollte.</p>\n\n<p>\"Dies ist der erste Preis, den Lapitec Chef erhalten hat, was unsere Forschung in Richtung Innovation best&auml;tigt und uns erlaubt, die besten Eigenschaften des <strong>Sintersteins</strong> zum Ausdruck zu bringen\", sagt <em>Marcello Toncelli</em>, der an der Spitze der Marke steht, und f&auml;hrt fort: \"Wir haben mehrere Jahre der Feinabstimmung dieses Produkts gewidmet, das durch ein Patent gesch&uuml;tzt ist und f&uuml;r den elektrothermischen Teil in Zusammenarbeit mit der Universit&auml;t von Padua entwickelt wurde. Unser Ziel ist es, Lapitec auf internationaler Ebene zur <strong>Referenzoberfl&auml;che</strong> schlechthin in der Welt des Kochens zu machen, und Lapitec Chef ist ein unverzichtbares und einzigartiges Werkzeug, mit dem wir dieses Ziel erreichen k&ouml;nnen\".<br />\n<br />\n&nbsp;</p>\n\n<h2>Lapitec Chef: Mischung aus &Auml;sthetik und Technologie</h2>\n\n<p>Lapitec Chef zeichnet sich durch eine perfekte Mischung aus &Auml;sthetik und Technologie, Leistung und Funktionalit&auml;t aus und wird durch eine doppelte Kochmatte aktiviert, die mit Magnetsensoren ausgestattet ist. Wenn sie auf das Kochfeld gelegt wird, interagiert sie mit den Induktoren unter der Platte und aktiviert die Touch-Bedienelemente und das System f&uuml;r insgesamt vier Kochbereiche, auch im Bridge-Modus.&nbsp;In Abwesenheit der Matte sind das <strong>Induktionskochfeld</strong> und die zugeh&ouml;rigen Anzeigen inaktiv und garantieren maximale Sicherheit. Die <strong>K&uuml;chenplatte</strong> bleibt also komplett frei: Es erscheint nur das Display samt kleinen Einschnitten, die angeben, wo die Matte platziert werden soll. Die <strong>Arbeitsplatte </strong>kann somit f&uuml;r die Zubereitung von Speisen, das Anrichten von Speisen oder sogar als Essbereich verwendet werden, dank ihrer porenfreien, nicht absorbierenden Oberfl&auml;che, die best&auml;ndig gegen chemische Mittel und Temperaturschocks ist und mit dem NSF Food Zone-Zeichen f&uuml;r den Kontakt mit Lebensmitteln zertifiziert ist.</p>\n\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n\n<h2>Anpassbar, frei von Kiesels&auml;ure und voller K&ouml;rper</h2>\n\n<p>Lapitec Chef ist mit allen <strong>induktionsgeeigneten</strong> Geschirrsorten kompatibel. Die Kochmatte besteht aus schwarzem Silikon in Lebensmittelqualit&auml;t mit einem Oberfl&auml;chenmuster, das ihre Leistung verbessert, und ist sp&uuml;lmaschinenfest.</p>\n\n<p>&Auml;sthetisch anspruchsvoll und technologisch fortschrittlich, kann Lapitec Chef in allen Nuancen und Ausf&uuml;hrungen der Lapitec-Reihe individuell gestaltet werden, kiesels&auml;urefrei und &bdquo;vollmundig&ldquo;.</p>\n\n<p><b>Lapitec</b> ist in der Tat ein &bdquo;Ganzk&ouml;rper&ldquo;-<strong>Sinterstein,</strong> der aus einer Mischung von 100 % nat&uuml;rlichen Mineralien besteht. Das in Architektur, Innenarchitektur und Produktdesign verwendete Material ist in gro&szlig;en Platten mit drei m&ouml;glichen St&auml;rken (12, 20 und 30 mm), in 18 Farbt&ouml;nen und 6 Oberfl&auml;chenausf&uuml;hrungen erh&auml;ltlich.</p>\n",
    "es": "<p><b>Lapitec Chef, </b>la<strong> innovadora placa de inducci&oacute;n</strong> completamente oculta debajo de la superficie, que permite la m&aacute;xima limpieza formal de los muebles, ha ganado el Kitchen Innovation Award 2023, un premio promovido por LifeCare.Network UG y anunciado con una ceremonia oficial en la feria Ambiente de Frankfurt.</p>\n\n<p>La victoria la decret&oacute; el p&uacute;blico que quiso elegirlo como el mejor producto seg&uacute;n los criterios de &ldquo;funcionalidad, innovaci&oacute;n, beneficio del producto, dise&ntilde;o e igualdad material&rdquo;.</p>\n\n<p>\"Este es el primer premio obtenido por Lapitec Chef, lo que confirma nuestra investigaci&oacute;n hacia la innovaci&oacute;n y tambi&eacute;n nos permite expresar las mejores caracter&iacute;sticas de la<strong> piedra sinterizada</strong>\" - dice <em>Marcello Toncelli</em>, al frente de la marca, quien contin&uacute;a: \"Hemos dedicado varios a&ntilde;os a la puesta a punto de este producto, amparado por una patente y desarrollado para la parte electrot&eacute;rmica en colaboraci&oacute;n con la Universidad de Padua. Nuestra ambici&oacute;n es hacer de Lapitec la <strong>superficie </strong>de referencia por excelencia en el mundo de la cocina, a nivel internacional, y Lapitec Chef es una herramienta indispensable y &uacute;nica a trav&eacute;s de la cual podemos avanzar hacia este objetivo&rdquo;.</p>\n\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n\n<h2>Lapitec Chef: mezcla entre est&eacute;tica y tecnolog&iacute;a</h2>\n\n<p>Caracterizado por una combinaci&oacute;n perfecta de est&eacute;tica y tecnolog&iacute;a, rendimiento y funcionalidad, Lapitec Chef se activa mediante una doble placa de cocina equipada con sensores magn&eacute;ticos; cuando se coloca sobre la placa, interact&uacute;a con los inductores bajo encimera y activa los controles t&aacute;ctiles y el sistema, para un total de cuatro zonas de cocci&oacute;n, incluso en modo puente. En ausencia de la Mat, la<strong> placa de inducci&oacute;n</strong> y las pantallas correspondientes est&aacute;n inactivas y garantizan la m&aacute;xima seguridad. La <strong>encimera de la cocina</strong> queda as&iacute; totalmente libre: s&oacute;lo aparece el expositor junto a peque&ntilde;as incisiones que indican d&oacute;nde colocar la alfombrilla. As&iacute;, la <strong>encimera</strong> puede utilizarse para la preparaci&oacute;n de alimentos, emplatar o incluso como zona de comedor, gracias a su superficie no porosa, no absorbente, resistente a los agentes qu&iacute;micos y al choque t&eacute;rmico, certificada con la marca NSF Food Zone para contacto con alimentos.<br />\n&nbsp;</p>\n\n<h2>Personalizable, sin s&iacute;lice y \"de cuerpo entero\".</h2>\n\n<p>Lapitec Chef es compatible con todas las bater&iacute;as de cocina aptas para<strong> placas de inducci&oacute;n</strong>. La alfombrilla de cocina est&aacute; fabricada en silicona alimentaria negra con un dibujo en la superficie que mejora el rendimiento, y es apta para el lavavajillas.</p>\n\n<p>Est&eacute;ticamente sofisticado y tecnol&oacute;gicamente avanzado, Lapitec Chef se puede personalizar en todos los matices y acabados de la gama Lapitec, sin s&iacute;lice y &#39;full body&#39;.</p>\n\n<p><strong>Lapitec</strong> es de hecho una<strong> piedra sinterizada</strong> de \"cuerpo completo\", hecha con una mezcla de minerales 100% naturales. Material utilizado en arquitectura, interiorismo y dise&ntilde;o de producto, est&aacute; disponible en grandes losas con tres espesores posibles (12, 20 y 30 mm), en 18 tonalidades y 6 acabados superficiales.</p>\n",
    "pt": "<p><b>Lapitec Chef, </b>a <strong>inovadora placa de indu&ccedil;&atilde;o</strong> completamente escondida sob a superf&iacute;cie, que permite a m&aacute;xima limpeza formal do mobili&aacute;rio, ganhou o Kitchen Innovation Award 2023, um pr&eacute;mio promovido pela LifeCare.Network UG e anunciado com uma cerim&oacute;nia oficial na feira Ambiente em Frankfurt.</p>\n\n<p>A vit&oacute;ria foi decretada pelo p&uacute;blico que quis eleg&ecirc;-lo como o melhor produto segundo os crit&eacute;rios de \"funcionalidade, inova&ccedil;&atilde;o, benef&iacute;cio do produto, design e igualdade de materiais\".</p>\n\n<p>\"Este &eacute; o primeiro pr&eacute;mio obtido pelo Chefe Lapitec, que confirma a nossa investiga&ccedil;&atilde;o sobre inova&ccedil;&atilde;o e tamb&eacute;m nos permite expressar as melhores caracter&iacute;sticas da <strong>pedra sinterizada</strong>\"<em>, </em>diz<em> Marcello Toncelli,</em> ao leme da marca, que continua: \"Pass&aacute;mos v&aacute;rios anos a afinar este produto, que &eacute; coberto por uma patente e desenvolvido para a parte electrot&eacute;rmica, em colabora&ccedil;&atilde;o com a Universidade de P&aacute;dua. A nossa ambi&ccedil;&atilde;o &eacute; fazer da Lapitec a <strong>superf&iacute;cie</strong> de refer&ecirc;ncia por excel&ecirc;ncia no mundo da cozinha, a n&iacute;vel internacional, e a Lapitec Chef &eacute; uma ferramenta indispens&aacute;vel e &uacute;nica atrav&eacute;s da qual podemos avan&ccedil;ar em direc&ccedil;&atilde;o a este objectivo\".<br />\n<br />\n&nbsp;</p>\n\n<h2>Lapitec Chef: uma mistura de est&eacute;tica e tecnologia</h2>\n\n<p>Caracterizado por uma mistura perfeita de est&eacute;tica e tecnologia, desempenho e funcionalidade, o Lapitec Chef &eacute; operado por um tapete duplo equipado com sensores magn&eacute;ticos; quando colocado na placa, interage com os indutores inferiores e activa os controlos t&aacute;cteis e o sistema, para um total de quatro &aacute;reas de cozedura tamb&eacute;m em modo ponte. Na aus&ecirc;ncia do tapete, a <strong>placa de indu&ccedil;&atilde;o</strong> e os respectivos visores ficam inativos e garantem a m&aacute;xima seguran&ccedil;a. O t<strong>ampo da cozinha</strong> fica, portanto, completamente livre: apenas o visor aparece junto com pequenas incis&otilde;es que indicam onde colocar o tapete. A <strong>bancada</strong> pode assim ser utilizada para a prepara&ccedil;&atilde;o de alimentos, empratamento ou mesmo como zona de refei&ccedil;&otilde;es, gra&ccedil;as &agrave; sua superf&iacute;cie n&atilde;o porosa, n&atilde;o absorvente, resistente aos agentes qu&iacute;micos e ao choque t&eacute;rmico, certificada com a marca NSF Food Zone para contacto com alimentos.</p>\n\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n\n<h2>Personaliz&aacute;vel, sem s&iacute;lica e de &#39;corpo inteiro&#39;.</h2>\n\n<p>O Lapitec Chef &eacute; compat&iacute;vel com todas as loi&ccedil;as adequadas para<strong> placas de indu&ccedil;&atilde;o</strong>. O Cooking Mat &eacute; feito de silicone preto de grau aliment&iacute;cio com um padr&atilde;o de superf&iacute;cie que melhora seu desempenho e pode ser lavado na lava-lou&ccedil;as.</p>\n\n<p>Esteticamente refinada e tecnologicamente avan&ccedil;ada, a Lapitec Chef &eacute; personaliz&aacute;vel em todas as nuances e acabamentos da gama Lapitec, sem s&iacute;lica e de corpo inteiro.</p>\n\n<p><b>A Lapitec</b> &eacute; de facto uma <strong>pedra sinterizada</strong> \"de corpo inteiro\" feita a partir de uma mistura de minerais 100% naturais. Um material utilizado na arquitectura, design de interiores e produtos, est&aacute; dispon&iacute;vel em grandes placas com tr&ecirc;s espessuras poss&iacute;veis (12, 20 e 30 mm), em 18 nuances e 6 acabamentos de superf&iacute;cie.</p>\n"
}
```